# Add items to Bootstrap Dropdown from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have a dropdown from boostrap such as this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
           <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
    <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to add list items to this boostrap dropdown menu from my C# code behind. I'm adding items through a String foreach Loop. How do I access the dropdown id, since its not displayed in the code behind because it requires ASP controls?

Comment: what about a repeater?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with it since I havent used bootstrap before @DanielA.White :)

Comment: its part of asp.net.

Comment: You can add runat="server" and an id to your <ul> tag and then access this in your code behind where you will have to generate the HTML and add it to the inner html of your <ul> tag (by referencing it by it's now server visible id).

Comment: This is an old question, but I found an excellent answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48922993/979174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a repeater.

```
Repeater1.DataSource = yourdatasource
    Repeater1.Databind()


<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate><Ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

    <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" href="#"> <%# Eval("yourfieldfromcodebhind here") %> </a>

    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: This looks good, however I'm trying to add items from a string foreach loop, what changes are required in your solution, mate?

Comment: you can create a list of string then while in your loop add to this list. Make the list be the source of your repeater http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string

Comment: Hello small question, I made the list my data source, but what do I add to the Eval(" ") part of your code?