# Inserting items into bootstrap-dropdown from SQL Table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am working on asp.net project and my code behind language is c#. I have one bootstrap dropdown in which i want to get the items from SQL Table. is there anyone who will help me in this regard. thanks in advance.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Category
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Action, Another Action and Something else items should come from database (Category) Table. Using c# language on server side is much appreciable.

Comment: You need to specify what type of ASP.NET environment you are using. For example you can make web applications with C# using WebForms, MVC, Core, Web API, etc...

Comment: Sorry, but WebForms isn't my area of expertise. I would add the keyword WebForms to your question and included it as a tag.

Comment: It is ok @DavidLee and thanks for the tag. my previous comment got deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ways to do it in WebForms, but first you need to make the **DIV** element of the dropdown menu accessible from the Code Behind.

See this snippet?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Category
        </a>
        <div id="myDropdownMenu" runat="server" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I added 2 attributes : **id="myDropdownMenu"** and **runat="server"**.

After this you can **go to Code Behind** to start populating the menu from a data source.

At least there are 2 ways to do this, as far as I know.

By manipulating the **InnerHtml** property, like this :

```
    private void DisplayMenuByConstructingHtmlTags(List<string> menuList)
    {
        var menuHtml = "";

        foreach (string menuText in menuList)
        {
            menuHtml += "<a class=\"dropdown-item\" href=\"#\">" + menuText + "</a>\n";
        }

        myDropdownMenu.InnerHtml = menuHtml;
    }
```

Or, by adding the menu as the **child controls**, like this :

```
    private void DisplayMenuByAddingChildControls(List<string> menuList)
    {
        foreach (string menuText in menuList)
        {
            var linkMenu = new HyperLink() { CssClass = "dropdown-item", NavigateUrl = "#", Text = menuText };
            myDropdownMenu.Controls.Add(linkMenu);
        }
    }
```

It's your call, which one to choose.

Btw, just to complete this example, you may try to call one of those methods from the **Page_Load** event, like this :

**EDIT :**

By your request, I've modified the samples by adding a connection to a table in a database. So, this is the module to load the data :

```
    private List<string> LoadMenuFromTable()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringName"].ToString();

        var retVal = new List<string>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT menu_text FROM Table_1", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        retVal.Add((string)reader["menu_text"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

And here's how you should call the module :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menu = LoadMenuFromTable();

        DisplayMenuByAddingChildControls(menu);
        // or DisplayMenuByConstructingHtmlTags(menu);
    }
```

Oh, and remember to import these two libraries to make this sample works :

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Brother I tried to implement your code in my project but it didn't work. and it seems your code is correct and i don't know to use it. can you explain me clearly with an example how to use it. please explain me by using  connection string, one sample table field and sql query. Hope you got my views what i am going to say..... @Erlangga

Comment: Be my guest, brother :)

Comment: Glad to hear that, my friend

Comment: This solution is simple & elegant - and rare! Many hours searching for this solution. Thanks.